# Remove object attribute with array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have an array of objects. Each element of the array has an attribute that I would like to remove.
My code:

```
        //remove the version key '__v'
        var elements = elements.map(function (element) {
            if (element.__v !== undefined) {
                delete element.__v;
                //console.log(element.__v);
            }
            return element;
        });//elements.map()
        console.log(elements);
```

If I uncomment the `console.log(element.__v);`, I get the attribute values of __v.
However, in the final output, the elements still contain __v attributes are still there.

Comment: Added the `mongoose` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have have a Mongoose model (assuming that you are using mongoose because of the __v attribute for versioning) that is freezed (prevents atributes form being deleted), one thing you can do is:

```
//remove the version key '__v'
    var elements = elements.map(function (element) {
        element = element.toJSON();
        if (element.__v !== undefined) {
            delete element.__v;
            //console.log(element.__v);
        }
        return element;
    });//elements.map()
    console.log(elements)
```

But this is not the optimal solution since you would loose lots of functionality that you might have coded on your model (like instance methods/ability to fetch more data via .populate, etc)

Use this solution if you dont need model features after removing the property.

Comment: So surprising ... How did you guess the OP use Mongoose? He didn't even mention it.

Comment: This is an assumption because I had the very same problem recently, and `__v` atribute for versioning is a mongoose thing. But I might be wrong. And even if I'm wrong assuming he is using mongoose, the symptons he described are usually related to freezed objects (you may have the same issue with sequelize models, for example)

Comment: I do run this inside of a mongoose find() query indeed. Thank you for the answer and explanation!